# How to select a DropDown from a list but HTML don't have select Tag using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I am new to selenium and i would like to perform a simple task I want to select a drop-down from a tab and i have used "http://www.spicejet.com/" as an Reference.
There is a Tab "Add-On" in webpage spicejet.com  and it contains Drop Down value i would like to select any one value from the list.
HTML code don't have select tag so Select class not giving me appropriate result.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="highlight-addons" class="">Add-Ons<span class="rightarrowclass">&nbsp;</span><span class="rightarrowclass">&nbsp;</span></a>
<li><a href="SpiceClubMembershipOffer.aspx">SpiceClub Membership Offer</a></li>
<li id="ctl00_lblSpiceClublink">
                                                <a id="ctl00_lblSpiceClub" href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$lblSpiceClub", "", false, "", "SpiceClub.aspx", false, true))'>SpiceCash/SpiceClub</a></li>
<li><a href="http://book.spicejet.com/SpiceMoneyTopup.aspx">SpiceCash Topup </a></li>
<a href="http://book.spicejet.com/RetrieveBooking.aspx?AddSeat=true">SpiceMax </a>
```

Please help me let me know how to move forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select a value from the `DropDown`, you have to first **`Mouse Hover`** the `WebElement` **`ADD-ONS`**, then to select **`SpiceClub Membership Offer`** you can use the following code block :

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='highlight-addons']"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(elem).perform();
List<WebElement> items = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='add-ons-tab']/li/a"));
for(WebElement myitem:items)
{
    if(myitem.getAttribute("innerHTML").contains("Membership"))
    {
        myitem.click();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: it worked but my question is u have used "//ul[@class='add-ons-tab']/li/a" and when i used that x path it was showing 1 of 21 elements so why selenium not throwing exception ?

Comment: can you explain attribute("inner html") ?

Comment: @AkulaBhaskar If using "//ul[@class='add-ons-tab']/li/a" showed you `1 of 21 elements`, it was correct. As my Answer have worked, please **`Accept`** the **`Answer`** by clicking on the tick mark beside my answer which is just below the `VoteDown` arrow, so the tick mark turns green. Thanks

Comment: yes it worked but i dont see the option to accept,Can you tell me?

Comment: Can u please let me know the concept of inner html "DebanjanB

Comment: `getAttribute("innerHTML")` is the purest form of `getText()` in a much cleanner way.

Comment: Ya understood Thanks @DebanjanB

Answer (score 1):

Its not a dropdown. It a menu, You can use `Actions` class to select the sub-menu you want. use below code :

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("highlight-addons"))).clickAndHold(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li/a[contains(text(),'SpiceMax')]"))).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: actually its not working,
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\chromegecko\\chromedriver.exe\\");
  WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("http://www.spicejet.com/");
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  
  Actions action = new Actions(driver);
  action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("highlight-addons"))).clickAndHold(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li/a[contains(text(),'SpiceMax')]"))).click().build().perform();
  Thread.sleep(5000);

}
}