# How to Xpath query all option tags containing the same attribute value

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I am trying to query text in within all option tags with data-store values labeled Book1. Below is the subject drop-down list.

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label>Cards</label>
        <select class="form-control giftcard-selector" name="giftcard">
                <option data-store="Book1" data-number="110" data-pin="333" data-balance="93.92" value="81372" style="display: none;">Book1: 1110 ($93.92)</option>
                <option data-store="Book2" data-number="111" data-pin="0619" data-balance="7.56" value="81371" style="display: none;">Book2: 112 ($7.56)</option>
                <option data-store="Book1" data-number="113" data-pin="8229" data-balance="10.24" value="81369" style="display: none;">Book1: 113 ($10.24)</option>
                <option data-store="Book2" data-number="114" data-pin="0984" data-balance="2.17" value="81373" style="display: none;">Book2: 115 ($2.17)</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

I have tried the following xpath to query all text within option tags data-store values labeled "Book1"  but it returns "Null".Any help would be appreciated.

```
//select[@class="form-control giftcard-selector"]/option@data-store="Book1"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you built your xpath wrongly, try this:

For the elements:

```
//select[@class="form-control giftcard-selector"]/option[@data-store="Book1"]
```

For the text:

```
//select[@class="form-control giftcard-selector"]/option[@data-store="Book1"]/text()
```

Comment: Correct! the attributes must be in brackets.

Comment: Hey Spencer the xpath you provided  returns a syntax error. However when i use xpath = //select[@class="form-control giftcard-selector"]/option@data-store it returns the first attribute data-store value of book1 but not both data-store values of book1..

Comment: Can you show how are you using this locator in your question? Because it was not supposed to show syntax error, I tested this locator, paste the piece of your java code that uses it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

`cssSelector: ".form-control.giftcard-selector option[data-number='1']"`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `<select>` element closely, all the descendent `<option>` elements are having **`style`** attribute set as `display: none;`. So [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) won't be able to locate them in a generic way.

---

### Solution

Presumably, the texts within the `<option>` tags are also represented through a `<ul>` and a couple of `<li>` tags and you need to interact with the option elements through those tags.

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Automating jQuery based bootstrap dropdown using Selenium and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59689093/automating-jquery-based-bootstrap-dropdown-using-selenium-and-java/59689509#59689509)
- [How to select an option from a dynamic dropdown using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51222724/how-to-select-an-option-from-a-dynamic-dropdown-using-selenium/51226055#51226055)
- [I would like to select a DropDown from a list but HTML don't have select Tag I am not sure should i use Select class or what](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47793001/i-would-like-to-select-a-dropdown-from-a-list-but-html-dont-have-select-tag-i-a/47794155#47794155)

Comment: Hey Debajan, there are no <ul> or <li> tags in this script.

Comment: @SpaceTech Can you cross check once again for `<span>` tags?

Comment: @SpaceTech Search for `//*[contains(., '1110')]` and try to locate the other nodes.