# How to click and select an option from a non select dropdown using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, webdriverwait

I'm starting automation with Selenium, it's the very first time im doing it alone and i can´t find the correct code for a dropdown list here https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form
at the end there is a "State and City list".. for state you have to click on "Select State" then it gives you the options so then you have to click on the option wanted.

This is my code, I've tried different options but this is the closest one to get a correct working of the code (but it's still not doing what it needs to be done)
I know it cant be done with a Select since it's a div and I can only use:

```
driver.findElement()
```

Code trials:

```
//Select state and city
driver.findElement(By.id("state")).click();     
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/div/div/div/div/div/div/form/div[10]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]")).click();
```

Image A:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYXu6.png)

Image B:
[image]

Image C:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keSyF.png)

Comment: Is there an explicit error or is it just not working correctly?

Comment: You may need to add a wait before fidning the dropdown element as it's getting added to the dom dynamically

Comment: Hello! No, it doesnt give me an explicit error, it works but the selecction it doesnt stay selected.. 
Yes, i will try doing that with the wait.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [drop-down-menu](/questions/tagged/drop-down-menu) is a non [html-select](/questions/tagged/html-select) element. To select an item from the **State** dropdown you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
driver.get("https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form");
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div#state div[class$='placeholder']"))));
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div#state div[class$='placeholder']"))).click();
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[contains(., 'Uttar Pradesh')]"))).click();
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Automating jQuery based bootstrap dropdown using Selenium and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59689093/automating-jquery-based-bootstrap-dropdown-using-selenium-and-java/59689509#59689509)
- [I would like to select a DropDown from a list but HTML don't have select Tag I am not sure should i use Select class or what](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47793001/i-would-like-to-select-a-dropdown-from-a-list-but-html-dont-have-select-tag-i-a/47794155#47794155)

Comment: Hello! it didnt work they way it should do because it doesnt give any errors but at the same time it doesnt do what it's suppose to do.. the selection doesnt stay selected..

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.get("https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.id("react-select-3-input")))).sendKeys("NCR");
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer]. Code is always more helpful when accompanied by an explanation.

Answer (score -1):

thank you to the people who took their time and tried to help me..
I found the solution!! perhaps there is another way but this is the way i found and since its the first time i did a code im really happy.
What i did was to go step by step till i found the "input" so i use sendKeys.(keys.Enter); because it didnt work with a .click();

And at later on i realized that with only ...........................................................
state.sendKeys("NCR") ...
state.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

would work also fine...so.. the code is way much simple..

public void selectStateandCity (){
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

```
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Select State')]"))));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#state > div"))));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='state']//div[@class='css-1g6gooi']"));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/div[@id='app']/div/div/div/div/div/form[@id='userForm']/div[@id='stateCity-wrapper']/div/div[@id='state']/div/div/div/div[1]"));
    state.sendKeys("NCR");
    state.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Select City')]"));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body//div[@id='app']//div[@id='city']//div//div//div[2]"));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/div[@id='app']/div/div/div/div/div/form[@id='userForm']/div[@id='stateCity-wrapper']/div/div[@id='city']/div/div/div/div[1]"));
    city.sendKeys("Delhi");
    city.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```