# Select value by text from a dynamic non select dropdown using Selenium Java

Tags: java, angular, selenium, xpath, drop-down-menu

I want to select value by text from a dynamic non select dropdown. I did some research and I found this code:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(ByMapper.getBy(dropdown));
element.click();
List<WebElement> options = element.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div"));
for (WebElement option : options){
    if (option.getText().contains(text)){
        option.click();
        break;
    }
}
```

Basically it put the dropdowns options into a List element, and run through in a for loop, and if the options contains text, click it and break the loop. However it is not working with this type of dropdown:

Snapshot:

[image: Dropdown]

Can you suggest what can I do?

Snapshot of Specific value:

[image: Specific value]

Note: The page is only available via private vpn, so I cannot share it.

Comment: Can you share page URL?

Comment: This is only available via private vpn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the value by text ***Teszt_5*** from a dynamic non Select dropdown you can use the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

```
String text = "Teszt_5";
WebElement element = driver.findElement(ByMapper.getBy(dropdown));
element.click();
List<WebElement> options = element.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='mat-autocomplete-panel mat-autocomplete-visible ng-star-inserted' and starts-with(@aria-labelledby, 'mat-form-field-label')]//mat-option//span[@class='mat-option-text']"));
for (WebElement option : options){
    if (option.getText().contains(text)){
        option.click();
        break;
    }
}
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Automating jQuery based bootstrap dropdown using Selenium and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59689509/7429447)
- [How to select a DropDown from a list but HTML don't have select Tag using Selenium Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47794155/7429447)

Comment: is this Angular? sure you can not use [ngModel] to know the value and the text of the option selected?. I know that we can use javascript in an Angular app, but really is necesary?